# JW Player 6.11 Skin Not Working in IE

Tags: youtube, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am working on a site that uses JW Player to skin YouTube videos. It works fine in Chrome and FireFox but just doesn't load the skin in IE. The video plays using the YouTube player but it just doesn't have any controls.

Even in the most basic of setups it will still not work, example below. I am using a Pro account and the full version of JW Player is 6.11.4923.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/127baEpAEeSLmSIAC0WXxA.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='video'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('video').setup({
        file: '//www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqz-KE-bpKQ',
        skin: 'beelden'
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am also getting an error in the console, screenshot below:

```
> Error handling "jwplayerMediaLevelChanged" event listener [0]:
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined function
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Are you really using a file URL without "http:" in front of it?

Comment: Usually no, I have been trying multiple combinations trying to get it to work, even with https:// or http:// i still have no joy.

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer [here we go](http://catspride.com/cat-matters/expert-advice/welcome-litter-lab/)

Comment: Ah, this is a bug in YouTube HTML5 mode that has been fixed in 6.12, which will be out soon. For now, if you set primary as flash, this will work.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer great that worked, thanks for your help, any idea when 6.12 will be out?

Comment: We are hoping to get it out this month.